# The impact of SharePoint 2016’s Excel Services Deprecations

Tags: sharepoint, business-intelligence, sharepoint-2016

I know you have to switch to Excel Online in Office Online Server Preview, but I’ve also read that these features are deprecated:

1. Trusted data providers
2. Trusted data connection libraries
3. Unattended service account

Here is what I use Excel Services for:

1. Connecting to a multidimensional/MDX Cube (NO TABULAR model is ever used)
2. Connecting to different data sources
3. Using the Excel workbooks themselves as data sources for SharePoint web parts AND dashboards (PerformancePoint Services)
4. Excel Web Access Web Part; and again, the Excel sheet connects to a cube, accepts parameters, and it is itself a data source for other artifacts. Part or all of the workbooks are used in PerformancePoint, webparts and report parts.

Sources considered:

- http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2016/03/connecting-excel-to-data-with-sharepoint-2016-and-office-online-server-2016/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn141153.aspx#bkmk_excel
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sharepoint-server-2016-whats-deprecated-removed-zeeshan-asad